# How do you use an arrow function with comparison operator for reduce method?

Tags: javascript, eslint

Using ESLint with Airbnb rules, I can't get a reduce method with comparison operator to work.

In the code below, the array named *data* holds objects, each with a property named *id*. The error messages ESLint throws are:

```
const maxId = data.reduce((prev, current) => {
  return prev.id > current.id ? prev.id : current.id;
});
```

> ESLint Error: arrow-body-style / Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body.

```
 const maxId = data.reduce((prev, current) => 
   prev.id > current.id ? prev.id : current.id);
```

> ESLint Error: no-confusing-arrow / Arrow function used ambiguously with a conditional expression.

```
const maxId = data.reduce(function (prev, current) {
  return prev.id > current.id ? prev.id : current.id;
});
```

> ESLint Error: prefer-arrow-callback / Unexpected function expression.

So how can I get this to work?

Comment: Have you tried `(prev, current) => (prev.id > current.id ? prev.id : current.id)` ? Of course you could also disable the `no-confusing-arrow` rule.

Comment: That worked, thank you very much!

Answer (score 39):

Wrap the body in parenthesis to make it not "confusing":

```
(prev, current) => (prev.id > current.id ? prev.id : current.id)
```

Comment: And if it's still not working, you need to set `allowParens` to true, like so: `"no-confusing-arrow": ["error", {"allowParens": true}]` in your .eslintrc

Answer (score 2):

@Felix has the solution to fix the linter problems, but to make your script work functionally you should use

```
const maxId = data.reduce((prev, current) => Math.max(prev, current.id), -Infinity);
//                                                    ^^^^             ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

that will work on `data` arrays of sizes other than 1 and 2.

Comment: Thank you! I see that Math.max() is more readable. [thread](stackoverflow.com/questions/1232345/speed-and-style-of-math-max-vs-ternary-operator-in-javascript)

Comment: Yes, but the actual problem of your reducer was that you expected `prev` to be an object, while it actually will be a number.